# use where_in in grocery crud as codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I want to use where_in() method as codeigniter , I tried to define it but not working correctly.please help.
I added this code in grocery crud library

```
 public function where_in($key = NULL, $values = array())
    {
             $this->where_in[] =array($key, $values);
        return $this;
    }
```

no errors but no result also.

Comment: just use [*where()*](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/where) with your desired where in clause

Comment: $key is DB field name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You M khalid Junaid.

where() use as where_in()

I have used where and works fine.